# UITableView not added to UIView when view loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios10

I discovered that the UITableView in the viewController is not in the view hierarchy. This is really strange and nothing like this had happened before.

I declare the tableView like this `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *table;` The tableView is properly implemented in the storyboard. I linked the declaration with the storyboard tableView, I also hooked up the delegate and dataSource. I even tried to call `[self.view addSubView]` the tableView is still not in the view hierarchy. By the way, the instance is not deallocated as well. I have no idea why this is happening. Thank you for your help! [image]

Comment: did u set any constraints for table view ? Also is datasoruce valid ?Did you check that  table delegate methods are getting called ?

Comment: I am using constraints for tableView and I check that the dataSource is valid.

Comment: what constraints did u apply for table view ?

Comment: Top, left right and bottom. Let me run it without any constraints.

Comment: Good news, the tableView loaded property after I deleted the old tableView and implemented a new one without any constraints.

Comment: you can delte this question if the issue is resolved, or you can post an answer and accept it.

Comment: One thing, the IBOutlet must be weak.

Comment: Absolutly, that's what I learned but I was afraid that it was a  deallocation problem

Comment: I'll try to redo there constraints as soon as possible.

Comment: It worked after I removed the tableView and all the constraints related to the tableView and recreated all of them. I have no idea why this occurred, maybe because I am switching from ios 9 Xcode 7 to ios 10 Xcode 8. Thank you for your help!